# Add udev rule alias for input device

Tags: linux, udev, raspbian

I am trying to add a udev alias rule for my xboxdrv (x-box controller) and I can't seem to figure it out.

```
dmesg | grep "input"
```

I see:

```
[    6.239955] input: Microsoft X-Box 360 pad as /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input2
[   27.057308] input: Xbox Gamepad (userspace driver) - Keyboard Emulation as /devices/virtual/input/input3
[   27.058307] input: Xbox Gamepad (userspace driver) as /devices/virtual/input/input4
```

It looks likes its input 3 and 4. So I check:

```
sudo udevadm info -a -p /devices/virtual/input/input3
```

which gives me:

```
looking at device '/devices/virtual/input/input3':
    KERNEL=="input3"
    SUBSYSTEM=="input"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{name}=="Xbox Gamepad (userspace driver) - Keyboard Emulation"
    ATTR{phys}==""
    ATTR{uniq}==""
    ATTR{properties}=="0"
```

And input4

```
  looking at device '/devices/virtual/input/input4':
    KERNEL=="input4"
    SUBSYSTEM=="input"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{name}=="Xbox Gamepad (userspace driver)"
    ATTR{phys}==""
    ATTR{uniq}==""
    ATTR{properties}=="0"
```

I think I have enough info to create my udev rule. I create a new file called `99-x-box.rules` in '/etc/udev/rules.d'. I added the following:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTR{name}=="Xbox Gamepad (userspace driver) - Keyboard Emulation", ATTR{properties}=="0", SYMLINK+="xboxcontroller"
```

I reboot. I don't see the alias in `/dev/input'. I also tried:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTR{name}=="Xbox Gamepad (userspace driver)", ATTR{properties}=="0", SYMLINK+="xboxcontroller"
```

Comment: I guess the symlink is not one level up in `/dev` either?

Comment: @goldilocks - no its not in `/dev/`

Comment: I think I resolved the issue. The xboxdrv adds a udev entry already 
`crw-rw---T 1 root input 13, 0 Mar 30 17:54 /dev/input/js0`

Comment: Then, please answer yr own question by providing a clear answer and marking it as answered with a green check-mark. Tx